# Using container image for Lamda function

Tags: python, docker, lambda

I have a very simple Lambda function that I'd like to test locally.

app.py

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return "hello"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
COPY app.py .
CMD [ "app.lambda_handler" ]
```

After I build my image with

```
docker build -t hello-world-3 .
```

I can't run it locally:

```
docker run -p 9000:8080 -it hello-world-3

[INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)
```

How can I invoke my image locally? It runs fine as Lambda function on AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have started your container with `hello-world-3` image, you can just run a `curl` command from your host (on another terminal) to access the specific endpoint exposed:

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations -d '{}'
```

You can find that at the end of the documentation here : https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-lambda-python, or also there : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html#images-test-AWSbase.

After calling your container, you should see your request in the terminal where you launched that container. For example:

```
START RequestId: da204eb4-7ff2-4382-85fb-44a01166194b Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: da204eb4-7ff2-4382-85fb-44a01166194b
REPORT RequestId: da204eb4-7ff2-4382-85fb-44a01166194b  Duration: 0.71 ms       Billed Duration: 1 ms   Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 3008 MB
```